# How to send email in ReactJS project

Tags: html, reactjs

What is the best way to send email at server side for a reactjs project .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React js can't send mail for you because of its a client-side application so you need a server-side application which will communicate with mail server. you can node js / laravel for that. Here is some example for nodemailer

```
'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {
    // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
    // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
    let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
            pass: testAccount.pass // generated ethereal password
        }
    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
        to: 'bar@example.com, baz@example.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
    });

    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

you can aslo follow their documentation https://nodemailer.com/about/

If you are using php framework like laravel follow [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail)

Answer (score 3):

Server sends email in a web app. so if you are using nodejs as backend you can use Nodemailer module.You can check more details of nodemailer at W3schools.

Comment: How i can pass parameter to it then

Comment: i didn't get what you want to ask.But if you want to pass Name of user and want to greet him for sign up.Then you can use data of variable for e.g.
var name ="user"
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  html: '<h1>Welcome</h1>'+name+'<p>That was easy!</p>'
}

for more info please visit at least once  https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp